# Explain the below Linq Query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

```
results.Where(x=>x.Members.Any(y=>members.Contains(y.Name.ToLower())
```

I happened to see this query in internet. Can anyone explain this query please.

suggest me  a good LINQ tutorial for this newbie.

thank you all.

Edited:

what is this x and y stands for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `x` is a single result, of the type of the elements in the `results` sequence.
- `y` is a single member, of the type of the elements in the `x.Members` sequence.

These are lambda expressions (`x => x.whatever`) that were introduced into the language with C# 3, where `x` is the input, and the right side (`x.whatever`) is the output (in this particular usage scenario).

An easier example

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var oddNumbers = list.Where(i => i % 2 != 0);
```

Here, `i` is a single `int` item that is an input into the expression. `i % 2 != 0` is a boolean expression evaluating whether the input is even or odd. The entire expression (`i => i % 2 != 0`) is a predicate, a `Func<int, bool>`, where the input is an integer and the output is a boolean. Follow? As you iterate over the query `oddNumbers`, each element in the `list` sequence is evaluated against the predicate. Those that pass then become part of your output.

```
foreach (var item in oddNumbers)
    Console.WriteLine(item);

// writes 1, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/LINQ_1.aspx) is a great LINQ tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Interesting query, but I don't like it.

I'll answer your second question first. `x` and `y` are parameters to the lambda methods that are defined in the calls to `Where()` and `Any()`. You could easy change the names to be more meaningful:

```
results.Where(result => 
    result.Members.Any(member => members.Contains(member.Name.ToLower());
```

And to answer your first question, this query will return each item in `results` where the `Members` collection has at least one item that is also contained in the `Members` collection as a lower case string.

The logic there doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me with knowing what the `Members` collection is or what it holds.

Answer (score 0):

x will be every instance of the results collection. The query uses lambda syntax, so x=>x.*somemember* means "invoke somemember on each x passed in. Where is an extension method for IEnumerables that expects a function that will take an argument and return a boolean. Lambda syntax creates delegates under the covers, but is far more expressive for carrying out certain types of operation (and saves a lot of typing).

Without knowing the type of objects held in the results collection (results will be something that implements IEnumerable), it is hard to know exactly what the code above will do. But an educated guess is that it will check all the members of all the x's in the above collection, and return you an IEnumerable of only those that have members with all lower-case names.